# setGeometry not workingin pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to set the width height of a QWidget percentage wise. But since we cannot do something like `min-height:20%` using QSS. I tried to use setGeometry function and recall this function on window resize event, but somehow it don't work, below is my code:

```
class mainwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        stylesheet = """
                    #mainwindow{
                        border: 0px;
                        background-color: #222;
                    }
                """
        scanelestylesheet = """
                    #scanelecontainer{
                        border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
                        background-color: #222;
                    }
                """
        scanstusconstylesheet = """
                    #scanstuscon{
                        border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
                        background-color: #fff;
                    }
                """


        container = QWidget()
        container.setObjectName("mainwindow")
        container.setContentsMargins(100, 100, 100, 100)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
        self.setWindowTitle("Neehack")

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setObjectName("scanelecontainer")
        widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(container)
        lay.addWidget(widget)
        effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(
            offset=QPoint(3, 3), blurRadius=25, color=QColor("#1a1a1a")
        )
        widget.setGraphicsEffect(effect)
        widget.setGeometry(0, 0,200, 20)
        widget.setStyleSheet(scanelestylesheet)

        scanstuscon = QWidget()
        scanstuscon.setObjectName("scanstuscon")
        scanstuscon.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        scanstusconlay = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        scanstusconlay.addWidget(scanstuscon)
        scanstuscon.setGeometry(10,10, 200,200)
        scanstuscon.setStyleSheet(scanstusconstylesheet)

        self.resize(1200, 800)
```

How do I set a QWidget size based on its parent's percentage or why isn't setGeomtry not working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective of the layouts is to handle the geometry of the widgets so setGeometry will not work. On the other hand, using setGeometry to modify the size together with resizeEvent to establish a percentage of the size is unnecessary since it is enough to set the stretch factor in the layout:

```py
class Mainwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        stylesheet = """
                    #mainwindow{
                        border: 0px;
                        background-color: #222;
                    }
                """
        scanelestylesheet = """
                    #scanelecontainer{
                        border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
                        background-color: #222;
                    }
                """
        scanstusconstylesheet = """
                    #scanstuscon{
                        border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
                        background-color: #fff;
                    }
                """

        container = QWidget()
        container.setObjectName("mainwindow")
        container.setContentsMargins(100, 100, 100, 100)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
        self.setWindowTitle("Neehack")

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setObjectName("scanelecontainer")
        widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(container)
        lay.addWidget(widget)
        effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(
            offset=QPoint(3, 3), blurRadius=25, color=QColor("#1a1a1a")
        )
        widget.setGraphicsEffect(effect)
        widget.setStyleSheet(scanelestylesheet)

        scanstuscon = QWidget()
        scanstuscon.setObjectName("scanstuscon")
        scanstuscon.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        scanstuscon.setStyleSheet(scanstusconstylesheet)

        # 20% = 20/(20 + 80)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        lay.addWidget(scanstuscon, stretch=20)
        lay.addStretch(80)

        self.resize(1200, 800)
```